# How to use RegExp grouping in javascript to parse strings

Tags: regex, typescript

I need to create a RegExp that will allow me to use groups to properly parse a string for some comparison logic.

consider the following list of strings:

```
const testSet: string[] = [
    "alpha-4181a",
    "alpha-4181a-2",
    "alpha-4181a_3",
    "example",
    "smokeTest"
]
```

Note the `-2` and `_3` which are valid methods of versioning in this naming convention. We wish to maintain support for such.

If we loop through the above set, I am expecting the entire string, WITHOUT versioning if it exists (as shown below)...

```
const returnSet: string[] = [
"alpha-4181a",
"alpha-4181a",
"alpha-4181a",
"example",
"smokeTest"
]
```

so far I have the following regex
`/([-_]\d?)$/gi`
which does properly identify the versioning at the end of the string. From here, I would like to create an additional group that matches everything that is NOT the versioning convention, but I can't seem to figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to match everything before the versioning at the end. But you also need lazy matching, which is what `+?` - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) for more.

```js
const testSet = [
    "alpha-4181a",
    "alpha-4181a-2",
    "alpha-4181a_3",
    "example",
    "smokeTest"
];

const resultSet = testSet.map((x) => x.match(/^(.+?)(?:[_-]\d)?$/)?.[1] ?? x);
//                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^ versioning here
//                                             ^^^^^ match everything before
console.log(resultSet);
```